# Open slack dialog by external app

Tags: slack, slack-api

The slack docs state that dialog's can be invoked using slash commands and buttons.

Is there however a way to not use either ? I would want my app to prompt user with a dialog. One option I found possible is to send a button via incoming web hooks or postMessage attachment than user clicks the button and opens a dialog but this seems like a needless step.

Another was to invoke the dialog via slash command but i cant find a way to invoke a slash comma d  ia web api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At least at the moment it is only possible in two ways:

- With a slash commmand
- With an interactive message

Both generate a trigger ID for the user, which is required to start your dialog and only valid for 3 seconds.

[Source](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#implementation)

Comment: Is it possible to add a text input field to attachments of a message like button?

Comment: no. text input fields are only possible in Slack through a Dialog

Comment: Is it possible to have api run the slash command in users slackbot channel?

Comment: maybe, but that would be a whole new question to ask

Comment: however, you can try it out. Here is the API command to issue a slash command: [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md). Note that you need a legacy token for it

Comment: I know it's possible to send a button message. Can this be expired like say 15 later if user has not clicked the message would be removed.

Comment: not automatically, like there is no "expire" feature in Slack. but your bot can of course delete his own messages again after a certain time if you want to.